# QVariant::fromValue(QMap<QString, int>) returns an empty map

Tags: c++, qt, qvariant

I have a function, which parses the file and fills a QMap<QString, int> with entries and returns a QVariant with value of that map:

```
QVariant FileParser::parseFile(QString filePath)
{
    QMap<QString, int> toReturn;
    ... (parse the file and fill the map)
    return QVariant::fromValue(toReturn);
}
```

When i check the contents of the map after calling it, i see an empty map:

```
QMap<QString, QVariant> words = FileParser().parseFile(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/Input.txt").toMap();
qDebug()<<words; //Gives QMap()
```

This function works fine if i return QMap<QString, int>, but wrapping it in QVariant gives an empty map. Why might that be?

Comment: You put `QMap<QString, int>` into the variant, but try to get `QMap<QString, QVariant>` back. Either build `QMap<QString, QVariant>` in `parseFile` and put that into the variant, or use `QVariant::value` to extract the correct type on the caller side.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik yep, you are right. `QVariant words = FileParser().parseFile(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/Input.txt");
    qDebug()<<words.value<QMap<QString, int>>();` gave me the desired result

Comment: @George please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mismatch where you put `QMap<QString, int>` into the variant, but tried to get `QMap<QString, QVariant>` back from the result. Either build `QMap<QString, QVariant>` in parseFile and put that into the variant, or use `QVariant::value` to extract the correct type on the caller side, i.e.:

```
qDebug() << words.value<QMap<QString, int>>();
```